# Select query to get values from another column, based on value in original column

Tags: mysql, sql

My question title may be a little vague, but this is more or less what I'm looking to do.

I've got two columns, and I want to grab all of the values of the second column (call it hash), based on the first column (call it nid).

So whenever the nid is the same, get all values from the hash column corresponding to that nid.

Something like `select hash from table where nid = the same`.

How would I go about doing this?

I see that there's Group By, but that just seems to get me only one hash value. Is there a way to do this with a SQL query?

```
| nid | hash |
|  2  | blah |
|  2  | test |
|  2  | goof |
|  3  | next |
|  3  | word |
```

So for example, I'd like to select blah, test, and goof if I'm trying to get every value associated with nid 2.

Comment: `whenever the nid is the same` same as what? you got an additional `nid` value in your second column?

Comment: So how exactly your output should look?

Comment: Why [select nid, hash from table where nid = 2 order by nid] is not working for you?

Comment: Are you trying do a dynamic pivot: {2, "blah, test, goof"}, {3, ...}?

Comment: Which would be accomplished by @gts's response (totally new to me) with separator ", "

Comment: @albe if no SEPARATOR arg is specified the default is ','

Comment: @gts, very nice, I had been looking for something like that even if it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @albe I think it does, as from what I understand he wants to group a set of values from column B grouped by column A. Glad it helps you anyhow

Comment: @gts, I agree, I meant "regardless of whether"

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will return a concatenated string of all matching values from column 2

So basically something like below:

```
SELECT nid, GROUP_CONCAT(hash) AS hashes
FROM tablename
WHERE nid IN (<somevaluesyouwant>)
GROUP BY nid
```